# How do i smoothly update ntpd's peer list?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, solaris, cname-record, ntpd

I have a network of solaris/linux servers that have ntpd configured to use a single internal server of stratum 2 through a DNS alias/CNAME. This is server is down for some time and the client servers' clocks are out of sync.

Since we have another internal server of stratum 1 (PPS), the DNS CNAME has been modified to point to the new server (which is up).

But using `ntpq -p` i can see that the client servers are still pointing to the old server.
It looks like they are not resolving again the peer name, so they don't get the new server IP.

How do i smoothly update ntpd's peer list ?

If i restart (x)ntpd, it's going to create timejumps.
I wish ntpd would have updated its peer list / configuration and smoothly synced with the new server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ntpdc` can do this for you -- specifically the `addpeer` and `unconfig` commands.
Basically update your config file, then use `ntpdc` to add the new peers and remove ("unconfigure") the old ones (*after* ntpd accepts the new peers as sane candidates for synchronization!)

You should also consider using a redundant device (routers with HSRP, or unix machines with HA failover/CARP/etc.) as your NTP source, or configuring more than one peer -- You don't want your clocks going insane just because one time server has a problem...

Comment: Thanks. But it would be better if ntpd refreshed/resolved its servers list instead of sticking to the one IP it resolved on start.

Comment: On few servers, i got 'permission denied', so instead i run ntpdate -uB <server> and when i sync, i restarted ntpd.

Comment: There are a bunch of problems with re-resolving the servers on some periodic basis (people using pool.ntp.org could get servers with noticeably different times, what do you do if DNS breaks, what do you do if DNS gets hijacked & sends you to a false-ticker, etc...) -- NTP also isn't the only thing that behaves this way (hostnames in firewall rules lead to the same kind of issue) :-)

Comment: This does not work for me: addpeer or addserver ask for a “Keyid: ” and refuse to work for empty or 0, and ask for an “MD5 Password: ” else and then say “***Permission denied”.

Answer (score 0):

If said servers are configured via DHCP (which they are, for easy renumbering, right? :) ) then you can update the DHCP server to send option 42 with the new server address.  They should all reacquire their leases (and get updated) at some point, right?